# Leaflet rectangle interaction

Tags: leaflet, rectangle

I 've built a map that can "listen" to the bounds of the whole map window, through leaflet's method:

```
getBounds()
```

What I would like, is the user to choose a more specific area with a rectangle.

The user interface could be something like the BoxZoom plugin:

http://gregallensworth.github.io/L.Control.BoxZoom/

https://github.com/gregallensworth/L.Control.BoxZoom

...but instead of zooming, I would like the map to get the coordinates of the drawn rectangle.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a plugin such as [Leaflet AreaSelect](https://github.com/heyman/leaflet-areaselect/).
Take a look at the [leaflet plugins](http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html) page for more plugins.